# File not uploading in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

This is the codeigniter function for file uploading

```
public function doctor_signup()
{ 
    $this->load->library('encrypt');
    $rand = time() . rand(0, 9999);

    if($_FILES["file"]["name"]!="") 
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)). '/uploads/';
        $config['max_size'] = '100';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';
        $config['name']=$rand;
        print_r($config);


        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload()) 
        {
            echo $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            exit;
        }
    }   


    $data = array(
        'username' => $_POST['username'],
        'password' => $this->encrypt->encode($_POST['password']),
        'name' => $_POST['name'],
        'address' => $_POST['address'],     
        'city' => $_POST['city'],       
        'state' => $_POST['state'],                                                 
        'photo'=> $rand,
        'email' => $_POST['email'],
        'date_of_join'=>date('Y-m-d H:m:s'),
        'landline' => $_POST['landline'],
        'mobile' => $_POST['mobile'],
        'specialist' => $_POST['specialist'],
        'comments' => $_POST['comments'],
        'degree' => $_POST['degree']
    );


    if( $this->db->insert('doctor_user', $data)) 
    {
        $this->load->view('header', $data);
        $this->load->view('user_created', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer', $data);
    }
}
```

But the file is not uploaded to the upload directory an also not giving any error. The uploads folder in under the home directory. Any suggestion.
Thanks

Comment: Have you enough permission ?

Comment: Check your upload folder permissions

Comment: I have all perimission

Comment: probably want to `print_r($error)` to get its output as it is an array.

Comment: Also, do you have error logging enabled in codeigniter? Set the `$config['log_threshold']` in `config/config.php`, and make sure the `/application/logs` folder has write permissions. It may give you something useful to go off of.

Comment: Check the size of the file which you are trying to upload..It should be < 100kb

Comment: Thanks i have not specified the allowed types $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png'; and it solved

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be because $config['name'] should be

```
$config['file_name']
```

Try renaming this and see if it works.  Also you are not using $config['allowed_types'] to specify what files can be uploaded.  Otherwise whats to stop someone upload a nasty file?